# How can I (best) convert an Option into a Try?

Tags: scala, scala-option

How can I (best) convert an Option returned by a method call into a Try (by preference, although an Either or a scalaz `\/` or even a Validation might be OK) including specifying a Failure value if appropriate?

For example, I have the following code, which feels kludgy, but does at least do (most of) the job:

```
import scala.util._

case class ARef(value: String)
case class BRef(value: String)
case class A(ref: ARef, bRef: BRef)
class MismatchException(msg: String) extends RuntimeException(msg)

trait MyTry {

  // Given:
  val validBRefs: List[BRef]

  // Want to go from an Option[A] (obtained, eg., via a function call passing a provided ARef)
  // to a Try[BRef], where the b-ref needs to be checked against the above list of BRefs or fail:

  def getValidBRefForReferencedA(aRef: ARef): Try[BRef] = {

    val abRef = for {
      a <- get[A](aRef) // Some function that returns an Option[A]
      abRef = a.bRef
      _ <- validBRefs.find(_ == abRef)
    } yield (abRef)

    abRef match {
      case Some(bRef) => Success(bRef)
      case None => Failure(new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref"))
    }
  }
}
```

It feels like there should be a way for the final match to be morphed into a map or flatMap or similar construct and incorporated into the preceeding for comprehension.

Also, I would prefer to be able to specify a different failure message if the call to return an Option[A] from the ARef failed (returned None) compared to the BRef check failing (I only care about knowing one reason for the failure, so a scalaz Validation doesn't feel like the ideal fit).

Is this a suitable place to use a monad transformer? If so, does scalaz provide a suitable one, or can someone give an example of what it would look like?

Comment: Do you mean something like `Try{ abRef.getOrElse(throw new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref")) }` or `abRef.map{ Success(_) }.getOrElse(Failure(new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref")))`?

Comment: @senia more the latter: `abRef.map{ Success(_) }.getOrElse(Failure(new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref")))`, but it feels like it ought to be possible - and more idiomatic - to build this into the for-comprehension somehow.

Comment: As a side note, why not use `filter` on `Option`—i.e., replace your `for`-comprehension with `get[A](aRef).map(_.bRef).filter(validBRefs.contains)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you start out with a `Try` from the get go with your for-comp then you can eliminate the match at the end.  You can do this by forcing the `Option` to a `Try` via `fold`.  Here's what that could look like:

```
def getValidBRefForReferencedA(aRef: ARef): Try[BRef] = {
  for {
    a <- get[A](aRef).fold[Try[A]](Failure[A](new OtherException("Invalid aRef supplied")))(Success(_))
    abRef = a.bRef
    _ <- validBRefs.find(_ == abRef).fold[Try[BRef]](Failure(new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref")))(Success(_))
  } yield abRef
}
```

With this approach, you can get different exceptions for the two different checks.  It's not perfect, but maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Ah, that is what I was expecting should be possible - missed the fold method (although it seems that only came in with Scala 2.10.x). Cheers @cmbaxter!

Answer (score 18):

You can use an implicit conversion

```
  implicit class OptionOps[A](opt: Option[A]) {

    def toTry(msg: String): Try[A] = {
      opt
        .map(Success(_))
        .getOrElse(Failure(new NoSuchElementException(msg)))
    }
  }
```

Scala standard lib uses this type of approach. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#companion-objects-of-a-type

Answer (score 15):

```
myOption
  .toRight(new Exception("y"))
  .toTry
```

This code will return either a `Success(x)` if `myOption` is `Some(x)` or `Failure(Exception("y"))` if it is a `None`.

Comment: This works perfectly and pretty straight forward. Exactly what I need, convert an Option[T] to a Try[T], and has custom Failure[U] when it has nothing inside the Option[T].

Answer (score 12):

### Short and simple

```
Try(option.get)
```

no need for fancy mapping. In case the option is empty you get an error like:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

Comment: Except you rely on Try mechanism as well as throwing exceptions instead of just converting values. This is inefficient.

Comment: @LMeyer : Creating a ``Failure(e)`` (which create an exception but does not catches it) is probably as much expensive as throwing and catching an exception. Anyone concerned to performance should avoid ``Try`` in the first place.

Comment: I think you are right. If performance is a concern, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017589/1549135 is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an `Either`, you can use `Option.toRight`:

```
def getValidBRefForReferencedA(aRef: ARef): Either[Throwable,BRef] = {    
  for {
    a <- get[A](aRef).toRight[Throwable](new Exception("Invalid ARef")).right
    bRef <- validBRefs.find(_ == a.bRef).toRight(new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref")).right
  } yield bRef
}
```

Using a `Try`, you can simply write your code in a very procedural way, by throwing appropriate exceptions where needed and wrapping the whole with
`Try.apply` (which will catch the exception and present them as `Failure` instances).

```
def getValidBRefForReferencedA(aRef: ARef): Try[BRef] = Try {
  val a = get[A](aRef).getOrElse(throw new Exception("Invalid ARef"))
  validBRefs.find(_ == a.bRef).getOrElse(throw new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me while I just necro-bumb this, because with Scala-3 I can now combine my favourite [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017589/3970469) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49488194/3970469) into my new favourite one:

```scala
extension [T](opt: Option[T]) def toTry: Try[T] = Try(opt.get)
```

What we're witnessing here is simply a case of [extension methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html) in [Scala-3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/new-in-scala3.html).

Answer (score 1):

**[Edited to identify different failures]**

Tried to simplify

```
def getValidBRefForReferencedA(aRef: ARef): Try[BRef] = {
  val abRef = for {
    a <- get[A](aRef)
    bRef = a.bRef
    result = Either.cond(validBRefs.contains(bRef), bRef, "Invalid B Reference")
  } yield result

  abRef.map {
    case Right(bRef) => Success(bRef)
    case Left(error) => Failure(new InvalidReferenceException(error))
  }.getOrElse(Failure(new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref")))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have worked out an alternative solution, although it still doesn't allow me to specify a different failure message for the case that the Option[A] is None versus the BRef not being valid:

```
def getValidBRefForReferencedA(aRef: ARef): Try[BRef] = 
  Try {
    (for {
      a <- get[A](aRef)
      bRef = a.bRef
      _ <- bs.find(_ == bRef)
    } yield (bRef)) getOrElse (throw new MismatchException("No B found matching A's B-ref"))
  }
```

I guess I am expecting it should be possible to have a way to quickly convert the returned Option[A] into a Try (in a suitably idiomatic Scala way - eg. inside a for-comprehension), then continue the processing (obtaining and checking the b-ref) while setting any appropriate Failures along the way.