# Monad transformer in Scala for comprehension to handle Option and collect error messages

Tags: mongodb, scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I've been looking at a lot of Scala monad transformer examples and haven't been able to figure out how to do what I think is probably something straightforward. I want to write a `for` comprehension that looks up something in a database (MongoDB), which returns an `Option`, then if that `Option` is a `Some`, looks at its contents and gets another `Option`, and so on. At each step, if I get a `None`, I want to abort the whole thing and produce an error message like `"X not found"`. The `for` comprehension should yield an `Either` (or something similar), in which a `Left` contains the error message and a `Right` contains the successful result of the whole operation (perhaps just a string, or perhaps an object constructed using several of the values obtained along the way).

So far I've just been using the `Option` monad by itself, as in this trivial example:

```
val docContentOpt = for {
  doc <- mongoCollection.findOne(MongoDBObject("_id" -> id))
  content <- doc.getAs[String]("content")
} yield content
```

However, I'm stuck trying to integrate something like `Either` into this. What I'm looking for is a working code snippet, not just a suggestion to try `\/` in Scalaz. I've tried to make sense of Scalaz, but it has very little documentation, and what little there is seems to be written for people who know all about lambda calculus, which I don't.

Comment: Don't know if you are aware but Scala 2.10 has the Try monad for handling success and failure: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try

Comment: Since you're dealing with the same monad (Option) Monad transformers is not what are you looking for, Monad transformers are to compose different type of monads (e.g. List[Option], Future[Try], etc. )

Comment: @GClaramunt Ah, OK. I assumed I needed an Option monad plus an Either monad, hence the need for a monad transformer. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd "try" something like this:

```
def tryOption[T](option: Option[T], message:String ="" ):Try[T] = option match {
  case Some(v) => Success(v)
  case None => Failure(new Exception(message))
}

val docContentOpt = for {
  doc <- tryOption(mongoCollection.findOne(MongoDBObject("_id" -> id)),s"$id not found")
  content <- tryOption(doc.getAs[String]("content"), "content not found") 
} yield content
```

Basically an Option to Try conversion that captures the error in an exception. `Try` is an specialized right-biased Either that is monadic (in contrast to Either, which is not)

Comment: You could replace `tryOption` by the `fold` method of `Option`, as explained e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17526264/1805388

Comment: @ValarDohaeris I find catamorphisms on Option very unreadable as they always start with Failure: "Guilty until proven innocent". But it's indeed more concise.

Answer (score 2):

`Try` may be what you're looking for, but it's also possible to do this using the "right projection" of the standard library's `Either`:

```
val docContentOpt: Either[String, String] = for {
  doc <- mongoCollection.findOne(MongoDBObject("_id" -> id)).toRight(
    s"$id not found"
  ).right
  content <- doc.getAs[String]("content").toRight("Can't get as content").right
} yield content
```

This may make more sense if your error type doesn't extend `Throwable`, for example, or if you're stuck on 2.9.2 or earlier (or if you just prefer the generality of `Either`, etc.).

(As a side note, it'd be nice if the standard library provided `toSuccess` and `toFailure` methods on `Option` that would make converting `Option` into `Try` as convenient as converting `Option` into `Either` is here—maybe someday.)

(And as another side note, Scalaz doesn't actually buy you much here—it would allow you to write `.toRightDisjunction("error")` instead of `.toRight("error").right`, but that's about it. As Gabriel Claramunt points out in a comment, this isn't a case for monad transformers.)